# bash for loop: failed to open file

Tags: bash

I have many directories with multiple files, each following strict naming convention. I tried this loop:

```
for s in /home/admin1/phd/results_Sample_*_hg38_hg19/Sample_*_bwa_LongSeed_sorted_hg38.bam; do 
    bedtools genomecov -ibam $s > $s
done
```

but get for every file:

```
Failed to open file
```

I just can't see the mistake

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with the loop - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if you are redirecting the output to the input file, bash will truncate the file *before* the process starts. Like this:

```
cat file > file
```

will result an empty file. Meaning you'll **loose** it's contents.

This is because bash will open all files which are subject of io redirection *before* it starts the command. If you are using `>` bash will additionally truncate the file to zero length. I don't know `bedtools` but I guess it expects non-empty files as input, that's why the message.

---

About the loop. Usually it is not a good idea to loop over the results of a glob expression like you did. This is because file names may contain the internal field separator of bash which would lead to inconsistent results.

I would suggest to use `find` instead:

```
find /home/admin1/phd/results_Sample_*_hg38_hg19 \
    -maxdepth 1 \
    -name 'Sample_*_bwa_LongSeed_sorted_hg38.bam' \
    -exec bash -c 'bedtools genomecov -ibam "{}" > "{}.copy"' \;
```

Comment: how can I specify output directory for .copy files?

Comment: Simply use `> "path/to/{}.copy"`